# SQL Server - OPENJSON error - JSON text is not properly formatted

Tags: json, sql-server

Azure SQL Server 2017 -

We have a table `dbo.MailArchive` with a field called `Mail_Body` which contains the body of an email.  The data always looks like this from record to record, just with different numbers, and Status message:

```
Status: Completed
Successful actions count: 250
Page load count: 250
```

But copy/pasting the above to test with will make it seem like there's no issue. YOu can use this to replicate the problem:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = 'Status: Completed
Successful actions count: 250
Page load count: 250' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);


SELECT CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourString, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')
```

Further, *this* is what the body of the email looks like if I view it in Word with hidden characters turned on:

[image: emailBodyPic]

This is the format that the data gets exported to the database in.

I'm trying to use `OPENJSON` to parse this data by line break, as such:

```
SELECT Mail_Body,
j.*
FROM dbo.MailArchive d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(d.Mail_Body, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
WITH (
   Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
   Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successfull actions count"',
   Request_Count int '$."Request count"'
     ) j
```

I get the following error when executing this:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ',' is found
>   at position 246.

Based on some advice I've received thus far, I'm thinking it might have something to do with that line break at the end of the body. But I can't figure out the right syntax to account for it.

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3e2dd21f23bfcac753760d02a64f61d) your issue.

Comment: @Larnu that's because you missed off the last line break - put the line break there and you have the issue.

Comment: *"you missed off the last line break"* This is why you need to provide sample data that is consumable, @Charleh . The sample data I can copy does not have that, and i can't copy an image's text.

Comment: @Larnu that's why I included the picture.  Up until now, the problem with anyone being able to help me figure this out is exactly what you've discovered - if you only copy/paste the data in the code block, it's not reproducible.  I will add this to my post.

Comment: @Larnu true, but it's debatable whether hitting "enter" at the end of the consumable bit of the data is too much effort to reproduce manually!

Comment: Yes, but provided a DDL script, not a picture of data, *doesn't* have that problem. Images of data aren't anywhere near as helpful as `text`.

Comment: I've added an additional sentence to my post to indicate that the picture with the last line break needs to be considered to get the entirety of the problem.

Comment: I've added DDL to replicate the actual problem.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu I'm not here arguing about whether you can copy text from an image or not (I agree, it tripped me up for a sec too), was merely pointing it out so that we can move this question along

Comment: Hi @JohnCappelletti you know I never even thought to go back to this, I got so caught up in trying to solve the issue with JSON.  Let me check that solution again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expensive fix, as `REVERSE` isn't cheap, but you could use it and `PATINDEX` to find the first characters that aren't a line break or carriage return, remove them, and then parse that:

```
DECLARE @YourString varchar(8000) = 'Status: Completed
Successful actions count: 250
Page load count: 250' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

DECLARE @PI varchar(7) = '%[^' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ']%';

SELECT j.Status,
       j.Successful_Actions_Count, --NULL as not in sample data
       j.Request_Count --NULL as not in sample data
FROM (VALUES(@YourString))V(YS)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(REVERSE(V.YS),PATINDEX(@PI,REVERSE(V.YS)))) PI(SY,I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(REVERSE(STUFF(PI.SY,1,PI.I,''))))S(FixedString)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(S.FixedString, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
                 WITH (Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
                       Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successfull actions count"',
                       Request_Count int '$."Request count"') j;
```

*This assumes that there could be 0 to many sets of `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)` at the end of the string. If it is only ever 2 sets, simply using `SUBSTRING` and `LEN` would be easier.*

Comment: Very interesting approach.  I'm testing it now - so I can properly test, can you help me with the syntax for running this against the table (`dbo.MailArchive`)?  I tried replacing your `FROM` clause with `FROM dbo.MailArchive` but having trouble understanding how to implement the field name `Mail_Body` into it.

Comment: You would replace `(VALUES(@YourString))V(YS)` with your table and alias, and then any references to `V.YS` would be to your column instead (with the table's alias as a prefix).

Comment: Thanks, checking it now.

Comment: When you say `REVERSE` isn't cheap - it's resource-intensive I take it?

Comment: It's an expensive operator, @Stpete111 . With one value, it's fine, but with a huge dataset, you'll notice a big performance hit having the reverse the string twice.